# Insert photo from Camera to e-mail - show size choice on iPhone

Tags: iphone, email, photos

On iPhone 4S initially when I selected in 'Photos' application option 'Email photo' I was asked about suggested size of photo to be sent.

Then I selected not to ask me any more and now the photo of last selected size is inserted all the time when I want to e-mail it.

I would like to return choice of photo size for inserting to e-mail.
I would like to reset my choice of photo size.

How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What size did you select initially? If you selected actual size, it's possible that it only asks for photos that are particularly large files, and sends actual size for photos that are not...

Comment: It seems you are right, I rechecked one more time with large photos

Comment: @gtmtg Is there any way to force the prompt to come up again? Or always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as I looked through Settings, as I thought, I couldn't find a way to change a settings like that. To be honest, I'm surprised that you had the option to remember the setting, as I have never had that (and still can't duplicate that).

I would recommend rebooting the phone to see if that, for some reason, fixes the problem. Also, as I'm sure you are well aware of, it should be mentioned that when you Message (MMS/iMessage) a picture or video it won't ask you the size, and when you email a video, it won't ask you the size.

If you really wanted to, you could reset the phone's settings (**Settings** > **General** > **Reset** (at the bottom of the list) > **Reset All Settings**). Honestly, I've only done the wipe all content and settings, so I'm not exactly sure what all it will reset, but it should take care of that problem. **Don't forget to back up just in case.**

Comment: I rechecked one more time, thanks to gtm's comment. Now I am not sure about option. Since I only started to use iPhone I had a lot of options everywhere new for me, possibly I mulled something, because I stopped to obtain option about photo size and I was not thinking about the size of photos..... sorry

Comment: @sergdev glad the problem is fixed/understood. Enjoy the phone!